# How to avoid misplaced objects when importing into Blender

Tags: python, rendering, import

I am new at blender so i dont understand much of it, i've got a problem at the moment of importing an ifc file as all the objects are in the same axis and not distributed in parts that should be. I will leave a video so it can be understanded better. On the top it shows how it should look, and on the bottom it shows how is imported.
[image]

[image]

Comment: In what software was this model exported?

Comment: It was exported from Revit.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is usually caused on export, not import, if transform methods were not applied upon export, the export method will not detect a software dependant transform, modifier, or parenting, try to check the options when exporting the objects, if there are options to apply transform and modifiers, make sure to check them. There's nothing much you can do on import since the data was not exported properly.